# Razor Pages PageModel binding for GET with AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, data-binding, razor-pages

I am having trouble getting binding to work with a specific set of circumstances. I am using Razor Pages with ASP.NET Core 3.1 to act like a controller for servicing AJAX calls. I have already added the anti-forgery token to the Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

My AJAX calls include the anti-forgery in the calls and look like:

```
function getTankConfig(tankId) {
    var json = { id: tankId };
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        url: "/Tank/Config",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        success: getTankConfigSuccess
    });
}

function getTankConfigSuccess(data) {
    if (data !== null) {
        // do stuff with data
    }
}
```

I have tried about every combination of binding technique. Using the parameter normally, adding `[FromBody]`, adding a public property and giving it the `[BindProperty]` attribute, using `[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]`. It seems like it was so simple when using a controller to do this, but I am not finding the magic for making it work with Razor Pages and PageModels.

Here is the simplified version of my PageModel class:

```
public class TankConfigModel : PageModel
{
    public JsonResult OnGet(int id)
    {
        TankConfigViewModel config = new TankConfigViewModel();
        config.Id = id;
        return new JsonResult(config);
    }
}
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you can just add it to the form using  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()  And I would think you'd want to use POST not GET...  you won't need to bind. (also check for double-posts when using ajax calls... I think I had to remove the @renderbody stuff in the layout, and re-write header/footer.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not using a form. This is pure JavaScript. I only use POST methods when data is going to change. As commented below, I am planning on changing to using just query strings.

Comment: ahh, ok... don't think GET requests need an anti-forgery token at all.  There's no need in that case.  (The purpose of these tokens is to prevent form impersonation.... if used the attacker has to play man in the middle, which makes it harder on them...)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this to your razor page

```
@page "{id}"
```

and fix ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Tank/Config/"+tankId,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
       
        success: function (result) {
                           getTankConfigSuccess(result)
                    },
         error: function (jqXHR) {

                    }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am coming to believe that GET requests were never meant to handle any data from the body of a request. So, I am probably going to just use a query string to pass the id to the handler. This approach does not require any bound properties and works without the need for the anti-forgery token.